# Task checkbox on Task Object

Tags: apex, related-list, tasks

I couldn't find the field name task(checkbox which differentiates task and event) On Task object.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not looking at the `Task` object. You're looking at the [Activity History object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm).

From that documentation, the field name is `isTask`. I'd imagine that the link to the actual `Task` is stored in the `WhatId` field.

Comment: thanks for the reply "No such column 'isTask' on entity 'Task'" is coming

Comment: Please take some time to read what I typed again. `isTask` is not a field on `Task`, but rather a field on `ActivityHistory`.

Answer (score 1):

The Task and Event records don't need an `IsTask` field, because we know what they are. The [`ActivityHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm) and [`OpenActivity`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm) objects contain both tasks and events, and are pseudo-objects, as they derive their values from two different tables. In normal database nomenclature, we'd call them "views", because they represent an underlying query of different objects.

Comment: thanks for the reply @sfdcfox I am creating a custom page where I need to show Activity History, there I need to show this Task. How can I do that.?

Comment: @Anzar The IsTask field is on the objects I've linked in my answer. If you're querying the Task or Event objects, you already know if it's a task or event. If you want to query ActivityHistory, you can do so as a sub-query, as in `select (select subject, istask from activityhistories) from account` (or whatever object you're querying).

Comment: thanks man...I have changed my code now I was thinking that checkbox is on task